# Allow input to add only numbers comma OR dot with regex

Tags: regex

So basically I have an input and I added some regex to it but I am facing some difficulties validating it the way I want. This is what I tried:

```
(/[^0-9 \,.]/, '')
```

So this let's me add only numbers comma and dot. So what I want is: The input allows only numbers 0-9, allow only 1 dot or 1 comma, only 3 digit maximum allowed after the comma or dot and the input should start with a number.

```js
$('.comma-validation').on('input', function() {
    var currentInput = $(this).val();
    var fixedInput = currentInput.replace(/[^0-9 \,.]/, '');
    $(this).val(fixedInput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="comma-validation">
```

Can someone help me solve it out? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code and regex looks funny, actually you're using a negated class (the opposite of what you want). Or did you mean to use `^` for matching start of the string? Guessing you want to match only digits and one dot or comma you could start with something like [`^\d*[.,]?\d*$`](https://regex101.com/r/2jxcZQ/1/) Please provide better context and code to your question!

Comment: Doesn't your regex mean *ignore* all the characters you specified? Or are you deleting everything that matches your regex? Isn't that a bit strange...?

Comment: Some examples of matches and non-matches would help

Comment: @bobblebubble I'm new to programming in general and i am trying my best. So what i want is: The input allows only numbers 0-9, allow only 1 dot or 1 comma, only 3 digit maximum allowed after the comma or dot and the input should start with a number. Is this possible?

Comment: Try with this one ^\d+[,.]?\d{0,3}$, if doesn't work please provide some examples

Comment: @MDP89 I't doesnt work and i cannot seem to get around it :/

Comment: @workservice does work nicely, [see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/2jxcZQ/2). If you're working with Javascript or another language, add more code. Or are using HTML input validation?

Comment: @bobblebubble jquery but it won't let me add it. This is what i had previously https://jsfiddle.net/wxh9ducs/

Comment: @workservice Added the code to your question, now it's better to understand (voted for reopen). I think you could try something like this with MDP89s pattern: [`var fixedInput = currentInput.replace(/^(\d*[,.]?\d{0,3}).*/, '$1');`](https://jsfiddle.net/1qw7mos2/)

Comment: @bobblebubble i have solved already. You and MDP89 helped me a lot . Thankyou